# Single sign on with OAuth2: saving refresh token in cookies

Tags: php, authentication, oauth, language-agnostic, single-sign-on

I need to implement centralised authentication server with single sign on.

One of the requirements are, that there should be no intermediate login screen (a.k.a direct login from service provider), so OAuth2 with password grant seems like the best option here.

User is read-only, authentication is used only to access specific content, which is the same for all users, the users can't change their personal data or anything else. We use user ID as an username and date of birthday as a password, it's not really secure, but that's not something we can control, because we get credentials from other 3rd party service, though we still want to make everything secure as possible, because user data includes such personal data as full name and home address.

To make it clear, next I will describe how I imagine OAuth2 and SSO flow to work together:

1. User enters his credentials and submits the login form in service provider
2. Service provider (SP) sends a request to identity provider (IdP), to check if credentials are valid (Request is signed with client id and secret as a base64 bearer token: `base64(client_id:secret)`)
3. If credentials are valid, IdP creates access token (5min) and refresh token (24h) and returns them to SP
4. On every user request, SP uses access token to receive user data from IdP
5. If token is expired, SP makes another request with refresh token to retrieve new access token. Request must be signed with client id and secret.

So it's pretty much, how OAuth2 password grant would work, probably hardest part is to make it work with SSO, I couldn't really find any working stateless implementations, so came up with this:

1. When access and refresh tokens are issued, IdP stores refresh token in a cookie.
2. When user visits SP for the first time, quick redirect to IdP is made, if refresh token exists in a cookie it’s added as query param to the redirect url and user is redirected back to SP. If no, some query param is added to identify, that user is not logged in, to avoid redirect loop.
3. SP uses retrieved refresh token to issue new access token (which is unique for every SP).

So access token can be used only by service provider, which it was issued for. And refresh token, can be used by all service providers, but to issue new access token client id and secret must be provided, so refresh token alone is useless.

Also forgot to mention that all websites use TLS.

What do you think about this implementation, is it secure enough? Maybe you have other suggestions?